# Can't stick elements to the bottom of a page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Please take a look at the demo code. When you scroll to the bottom, the *stick to top* element is always at the top, but the *stick to bottom* element does not stick to the bottom at all. Is there anything wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="height: 2000px;">
        <div class="col bg-success">
          <div class="col bg-info" style="position: sticky; top: 0">
            Stick to top
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col bg-danger">
          <div class="col bg-warning" style="position: sticky; bottom: 0">
            Stick to bottom
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: you might wanna check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55965662/if-you-specify-bottom-0-for-position-sticky-why-is-it-doing-something-diffe

Comment: Try using `position: fixed`

Comment: By default a flexbox container (your `.row`) is a 'row of columns' (`flex-direction: row`), but what you need is a 'column of rows' (`flex-direction: column`). I don't see the CSS defining that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend paying attention [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54610362/17182878) to a similar problem. In your case, accordingly, you can try to make the parent element as flex (`.d-flex` in Bootstrap), and for the stick element add `margin-top: auto` (`.mt-auto` in Bootstrap).

A modified example is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="height: 2000px;">
        <div class="col bg-success">
          <div class="col bg-info" style="position: sticky; top: 0">
            Stick to top
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col bg-danger d-flex">
          <div class="col bg-warning mt-auto" style="position: sticky; bottom: 0">
            Stick to bottom
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```