# .table-responsive + position sticky doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Position sticky works on my `<th>` until I wrap my table with a div.table-responsive

position sticky work on my `<th>` if I remove the .table-response div but I really want to make a responsive table and I don't understand why wrap my table with this div doesn't allow the position sticky

This work perfectly fine :

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
  <caption>List of users</caption>
  <thead class='thead-dark sticky-top'>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

But this doesn't work why ?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
    <caption>List of users</caption>
    <thead class='thead-dark sticky-top'>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `table-responsive` comes with `overflow:auto`  that's why : *-" A stickily positioned element is an element whose computed position value is sticky. It's treated as relatively positioned until its containing block crosses a specified threshold (such as setting top to value other than auto) within its flow root (or the container it scrolls within), at which point it is treated as "stuck" **until meeting the opposite edge** of its containing block. "-* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: note that the first snippet doesn't work on Chrome .. for the overflow thing you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55592104/8620333