Sticky a column of table
`actionColumn = {
Cell: (instance: any) => {
const {
row,
webComponentsReactProperties
} = instance;
const isOverlay = webComponentsReactProperties.showOverlay;
    return ( <
        FlexBox style = {
            {
                gap: "5px"
            }
        } >
        <
        Button onClick = {
            () => this.handleEditClick(row.original)
        }
        icon = "edit"
        disabled = {
            isOverlay
        }
        /> <
        Button onClick = {
            () => this.handleDeleteClick(row.original)
        }
        icon = "delete"
        disabled = {
            isOverlay
        }
        /> < /
        FlexBox >
    );
},
Header: $localize`Action`,
accessor: ".",
disableFilters: true,
hAlign: "Center",
disableGroupBy: true,
disableResizing: true,
disableSortBy: true,
id: "actions",
    position: sticky;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: white;
width: 100,

};`
Action Column need to sticky on screen right side. But this one not working

Possiblity a duplication - see the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54804406/why-is-position-sticky-not-working-with-core-uis-bootstrap-css

My case its not work as i'm using @ui5/webcomponents-react
